# Error 4 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am supposed to do a project in class where I have to setup a website from scratch using C# and ASP.NET.

My objective is to create a contact form in this case where the function is to send an email to the designated address upon the clicking of a button where I've tried to create by Googling the codes.
However, I've encountered the error , "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.   "

Could anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

The codes that I've used on the page are as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

<%@Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>;
<script language="c#" runat="server">;



public partial class ContactUs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.To = "sarahhhhh@gmail.com";
        msg.From = nameTB.text;
        msg.Subject = subjectTB.text;
        msg.Body = messageTB.text;
        lblStatus.Text = "Sending...";

        SmtpMail.Send(msg);
        lblStatus.Text = "Sent email (" + txtSubject.Text + ") to " + txtTo.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a code behind file or aspx file?

Comment: (I'd strongly recommend using a codebehind rather than putting all your C# in the .aspx file...)

Comment: Looks like aspx from `import` directives, but written as CS (with using in the beginning... You need to decide what type of file it is and stick to syntax of given type.

Comment: Hi, this is a aspx.cs file.
I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by a codebehind file, could you explain in greater detail?

Comment: add using System.Web.Mail; and remove <%@Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>;
<script language="c#" runat="server">;

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines:-

```
<%@Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>;
<script language="c#" runat="server">;
</script> //If it's present
```

And add `using System.Web.Mail;` at the top like other namespaces are included. Your this file with `aspx.cs` file extension is called Code Behind file, You should read the basics first. Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb(v=vs.100).aspx).